# How to access "Comment" field using Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

Adwords Editor allows to view/update "Comment" field. The same can be modified using CSV Export/Import. But, I am unable to get the same using Adwords API.

BTW, I want a way for my business user to "tag" certain Ad Group so that my script does alter those ads accidentally. Any alternatives are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access "Comment" field outside Adwords Editor, because it is local field stored on the desktop. So accessing the same using API is out of question.

I am now using Labels to achieve my requirement.